# Evaluate an integral over a range of initial values

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I have an integral that I would like to evaluate over a continuous range of lower limits and plot the result. I can't figure out how to tell Mathematica to do this.

$$Q_c(u) = \frac{2\pi}{c^2} \left(\frac{k_B T_c}{h}\right)^3 \int_a^\infty \frac{u^2}{e^u-1}du$$

Here's my Mathematica code so far.

```
Q[x_] := x^2/(Exp[x] - 1);
Kc = 2*\[Pi]/c^2*(kb*300/h)^3;
a[vg_] := vg/(kb*300);
z = 1.0;
Integrate[Kc*Q[x], {x, a[z], \[Infinity]}]

2.85817*10^9
```

It's simple enough to evaluate it for any specific value of $a$ but when I try to make a new function containing the integration Mathematica won't plot the results.

```
qloop[z_, Q[x_]] := Integrate[Kc*Q[x], {x, a[z], \[Infinity]}];
Plot[qloop[z, Q[x]], {z, .5, 2.5}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just plot your integral (whatever Q is, its unit is 1/(m^2 s)) like

```
c = 3*10^8; kb = 1.38/10^23; T = 300; h = 6.626/10^34; 
Plot[((2*Pi)/c^2)*((kb*T)/h)^3*
NIntegrate[u^2/(Exp[u] - 1), {u, a, Infinity}], {a, 0, 10}, 
AxesLabel -> {"a", "Q"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Instead of passing `Q[x]`, pass just `z` to qloop. Inside qloop, `x` is set by the integrate itself and passed to `Q[x]` then. Also change the function to use `?NumericQ`.

You did not have values for c and h (I assumes these are speed of light and Planck constant).

```
ClearAll[x,a,qloop];
Q[x_?NumericQ] := x^2/(Exp[x] - 1);
kb = 1;
c = QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity["SpeedOfLight"]];
h = QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity["PlanckConstant"]];
Kc = 2*π/c^2*(kb*300/h)^3;
a[vg_] := vg/(kb*300);

qloop[z_?NumericQ] := Integrate[Kc*Q[x], {x, a[z], ∞}];
Plot[qloop[z], {z, .5, 2.5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]